# Set state after component did mount?

Tags: reactjs

A story:

I have a server rendering but some part of my app cannot be done there, since they use document(react-art library for drawing on a canvas).
I cannot render everything in the same from, because react will say that the code received from a server and and client one are not the same.

So my solution is to render some part of my app on the server, then render this part on a client and, in the next frame, render everything that is impossible to render on a client.

So I was thinking about using `setState` in `componentDidMount` and trigger DOM update, so it can contain rendered client part which cannot be rendered on a server, but eslint says it is not good to set state in `componentDidMount`. Logically I cannot say why it is bad in this case. Generally it is not good because it triggers DOM update, but in my case, this is what I actually need.

What would you suggested in this case?

**Edit 1:**
Fixed typo, I mean `componentDidMount` not `componentDidUpdate`.

**Edit 2:**
[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/YYgETx8soUo) is the same issue, but they use changing state in `componentDidMount` as a workaround.

Comment: Have a look at [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getinitialstate) for `getInitialState`.

Comment: `getInitialState` is for setting an initial value, but I have no problems with that. My problem is: "How to change the state after component is mounted?"

Answer (score 1):

I've just coded a similar scenario and happily used componentDidMount disabling ESLint's warning. IMHO it is perfectly valid ONLY in universal rendering scenarios.

Why: Using setState in [discouraged](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md) in componentDidMount because you'll trigger an additional, unnecessary render.

However in a universal scenario where you want to differ server and client behaviour, you'll want that additional render and in order to prevent 'could not reuse markup' errors, you'll want it just after react reconciles with the server rendered DOM. In brief: You'll render twice in any case.

I don't however recommend coding this behaviour in a leaf / dumb component because doing so would require the supposedly dumb component to have some knowledge of it's environment (client / server) and present a design problem. Creating a component that would set the props of the dumb component would be the obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting state in `componentWillMount` or `componentWillUpdate`.

Be careful with `componentWillMount`, it can also be called server side.

Comment: I cannot set state in `componentWillMount` because it will render different data to the one I get from the server.

Comment: And I cannot do this in `componentWillUpdate`, it is not called in first rendering and it is not called at all in this case. My problem is not "where to set the state", the problem is: "How to change the state after component is mounted?" Or any other alternative for described issue above.

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is that after your component is mounted, data on server and client changes and you want to keep component in sync with changing data.
I recommend you have a look at the flux or redux architectures of react. For example flux is implemented in a way that when anything in component changes it triggers action and listens to the store. And when anything in store is changed then component will re render itself.

Comment: I already use redux, but this is a different problem. My data is not changing, I would render everything on a server I have no pain in case I dont use libraries which cannot be used on a server(react-art in my case). Again, I want to know how to trigger components update after my app is mounted. This is an event what I need, but I setting state in componentDidMount is not allowed in airbnb eslint.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how to trigger components update after my app is mounted.

In React, the conventional way to "push" state onto a component is using `props`, not `state`. If your application needs to acquire information client-side and adjust component `state` accordingly, you should implement `componentWillReceiveProps`.

If you feel that the state rendered on the server and in-browser are of the same kind, and don't want the hassle of tracking which properties belong `this.state` v. `this.props`, I suggest something like the following:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState( Object.assign({}, this.state, nextProps) );
}
```

This will merge the passed properties into the component state, so that they can be accessed using `this.state`.

Comment: My problem is not about changing state, everything is great with my state, it should not change. The thing is that my client code is different to the one from the server. After sending html from the server I have an empty container, on a client side I have a data there. I cannot render those stuff on a server. So I have warning: "React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid.". So I want to render html from a server and then add client part. That is why I need to have a callback, an even handler where I can change some property in my state and render client part.

Comment: It would be perfect if I can just render once without any hacks, but I get the warning.

Comment: @RossKhanas My answer does not describe a hack, but the normal way of "changing some property in my state". It seems that none of your attempts to describe the problem have clarified it; consider adding some code samples to your question, and an explanation of why simply passing the client-side data as props will not solve issue.

Comment: I have no problems with a "changing some property in my state". groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/YYgETx8soUo Here is the same problem with a solution I mentioned as well. There is a gist in the second response, I suspect this is actually the best solution for now, despite eslint throws a warning.

Comment: Anyway, I made a new issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007875/how-to-make-a-server-rendering-with-part-of-the-code-run-only-on-a-client
I hope it will be more clear than this one, to much confusion here. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_component_life_cycle.htm) link About `ReactJS - Component Life Cycle`.
you should use from `componentWillMount` cycle. `componentWillMount` is executed before rendering, on both server and client side.

Comment: I cannot do that, because I cannot render part of my app on a server, `react-art` has window dependency that breaks server rendering.

Comment: It can work for the first render, but not, because when the page is rendered, its html is different to the one sent from the server. So I have a warning. That is why I want to have this kind of callback, to render client part in the next frame.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent usage of `setState` in `componentDidMount`.

Updating the state after a component mount will trigger a second `render()` call and can lead to property/layout thrashing.
The following patterns are considered warnings:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            data: data
        });
    }
}
```

The following patterns are not considered warnings:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
         this.setState({
            data: data
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
       ...
    }
}
```