# How to make a server rendering with part of the code run only on a client?

Tags: reactjs, server-rendering

I have `window` dependency in some of modules I use, so I cannot render part of my app on a server. However the content send from a server should be the same as a content rendered on a client first time, otherwise there will be a: "React attempted to use reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid" warning.

Seems like I need to do some workaround, render the content from a server and then, after component is mounted, render a client only part. Similar issue described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/YYgETx8soUo).

I feel this is the best solution, however eslint from AirBnB throws an error that changing state in `componentDiMount` is not good.

Do you have better ideas?

Comment: Using `this.setState` in `componentDidMount` should be fine. What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: @Jack here is an eslint rule for that: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md

Comment: Well...they're saying don't do it because it will force a re-render,  but considering you're doing it solely because you want to do something on the client-side only your use is one of the exceptions to their rule.

Comment: Yes, I feel like that. So I think it is just better to disable this rule in one particular place. But just in case there are better solutions (logically this sounds like a correct one) I wanted to ask a question and make sure this one is the best. Thank you.

Comment: Thereare could be a solution when a content rendered inside some container is a "client only" so it can be rendered without server side thing and any warnings. In that case there would be no need to do this workaround and change state after component is mounted.

Comment: I don't follow your last comment.